# Gradle config file get unknown property with System.setProperty

Tags: java, gradle

I have a problem with my settings.gradle :

```
pluginManagement {
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStore', trust_store_location)
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword', trust_store_password)

}
```

When I try to run my project I have this error :

```
Could not get unknown property 'trust_store_location'
```

I have a file `param.properties` with this parameter `trust_store_location=conf/truststore.jks`

But I don't know where can I put this file for working... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices here :

**1#** Put your properties in the `gradle.properties` file. `Gradle` automatically reads this file and give you access to the properties as variables

**2#** Manually load `param.properties`

```
pluginManagement {
    def props = new Properties()
    file('param.properties').withInputStream { props.load(it) }
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStore', props.getProperty('trust_store_location'))
    System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword', props.getProperty('trust_store_password'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! I have another error when I try to manually load : `The pluginManagement {} block must appear before any other statements in the script`.